# wp7 TextWrapping not working?

Tags: windows-phone-7, textblock

In Orientation="Horizontal" TextWrapping not working below code please check the mistake tell me.

Mycode:

```
<StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400">
                            <TextBlock Text="dfgdfdgdfgfdgdfg" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" vs " FontSize="30" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Indiaafda (text)" Foreground="Bisque" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                </StackPanel>
```

I wnat like this:

```
South AfricaTeamPlayed vs west
Indies (test)
```

but output display this,

```
South AfricaTeamPlayed vs west
                  Indies (test)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `Grid` instead of `StackPanel`.

Something like this,

```
    <Grid Width="400" Margin="40,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="dfgdfdgdfgfdgdfg" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBlock Text=" vs " FontSize="30" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Indiaafda (text)" Foreground="Bisque" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
```

I will probably re-design the whole thing to be something like this,

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Margin="40,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="dfgdfdgdfgfdgdfg" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" vs " FontSize="30" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Indiaafda (text)" Foreground="Bisque" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="where other stuff goes" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**UPDATE**

```
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="40,0">
        <TextBlock Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <Run Text="south africa"/>
            <Run Text="vs"/>
            <Run Text="windows phone"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: dfgdfdgdfgfdgdfg this sentence is also split one by one . i want to continue textBlock like this, dfgdfdgdfgfdgdfg vs Indiaafda (text) it will coming two line. In tyhis code first sentence showing two lines and second sentence showing two line.

Comment: So you want the first text in one line and wrap the second one in two lines? Try changing the first ColumnDefinition to Auto width.

Comment: i first text coming correct third test showing vertically not second line.

Comment: You mean you want the third one goes all the way to the left in the second line? Can you make your question clearer? I am so lost...

Comment: I am creating 3 textBlock three are displaying one after one that good. but third one while reach end it's not coming second line.it's taking some width data displaying particular width only.

Comment: do you want the third one to go all the way to the left in the second line?

Comment: yes, 1st one "southafrica" 2nd one "vs" 3 one "wondows phone".southafrica vs windows it is complete one line phone is display second line.

Comment: Alright... I am just gonna have a guess, pls see my updated answer.

Comment: it's display but not corrcet. see i am add my question like that i want.

Comment: glad finally got what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete Width property of Stack Panel and then try.